# Is it possible to use a Nexus Repository to store a Gradle Remote Build Cache?

Tags: gradle, caching, nexus

I have access to a private Nexus Repository and would like to speed up my CI builds and thought that I could use the private repository to store and access my build cache. Is this a possibility or a dead end?

Answer (score 3):

It works like a breeze.
Just create a "Raw" repository and give a user write permission for it.
This user then is used to fill the cache and you can use another user or anonymous access to read from the cache.
I just tried it minutes ago.
Any web server that supports `PUT` for storing files and `GET` for retrieving the same files should be fine with the default `HttpBuildCache` implementation.
You can even provide an own client-side implementation to use any remote service you want as build cache.

Comment: My project have nexus server as a dependency resolution manger, how can I leverage the same for build cache?

Comment: @Bytecode that's exactly what I say in my answer, so I don't get your question.